# Where can I warn users about broken backup software

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was using a commercial, pay-per-month backup solution for several years. Recently I had to restore some files. The software failed and did not restore important files, showing a cryptic error message for which I cannot find any help anywhere in the internet. I tried to contact support several times, but there's no answer so far. So it turned out I lost the files, and I didn't have any reliable backup for all those years.

I would like to warn other users which might be using this product. Of course I'm feeling angry and this is part of why I want to do this, but another thing is - there might be many many users there which are using this software and have no idea that they have no backup at all.

My question is, how can I inform other users about this? Does this belong to Server Fault site, or Super User site, or nowhere at Stack Exchange?

Comment: As I received many down votes, I would like to ask where can I ask about if something belongs to SE or not? I thought meta is the right place but I guess I'm wrong?

Comment: SE is not for such review, but please take note to do restore test from time to time, it’s an essential  routine in IT world to validate in the minimum that the media still work.

Comment: Well, it's not trivial to restore 600GB of data from the cloud and make sure it is not damaged. And still, I would prefer the backup tool that stores consistent data and not garbage :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warn? Not directly. That said

> The software failed and did not restore important files, showing a cryptic error message for which I cannot find any help anywhere in the internet. I tried to contact support several times, but there's no answer so far.

Assuming you have the error message and a good, practical question about the error message, and file recovery attempts failing, you have a decent way of *documenting* the problem and maybe someone might know. Its not a way to warn, but at least other people searching for the problem, and the backup software might be able to find it

(Then go maybe see if you can get it slashdotted, or whatever the cool kids do these days - and use that as a way to rant about how terrible it is).

Answer (score 9):

There are lots of product review sites out there on the internet.

SE isn't one of those places.